# TensorFlow-GPU 1.12.0 + CUDA 9 + cuDNN 7.41 on Windows throws DLL load failed. Same bundle works on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

As in title I have
CUDA 9.0.176
cuDNN v7.4.1
TF-GPU 1.12
Python 3.6.6

I can confirm that path both to bin/lib for CUDA is in a PATH and also there is a path to cuda folder (not sure why if same files were copieed to CUDA folder (nvidia not a custom one as per tutorials)).

```
import tensorflow
>>> import tensorflow
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
         File "D:\OtherCode\Teest1\test1\lib\site- 
     packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
     disable=unused-import
      File "D:\OtherCode\Teest1\test1\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "D:\OtherCode\Teest1\test1\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "D:\OtherCode\Teest1\test1\lib\site- 
    packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
 from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I've tried pretty much many other different bundles after that (using Tensorflow table showing tested configurations), but none of them works.

I have all files in System32 that I've found info about, I have VS 2017 / 2019 + install the compile for 2015.

Nothing works.

Is there anything on Windows that I need to be aware of  ?

Same bundle works fine on Ubuntu pretty much instantly, on Windows it fails terribly.

I would prefer use windows as there is number of issues with ubuntu (most of hardware is not supported on Ubuntu + I am using VS Studio for most of the projects).

I've tried CUDA 8.0, CUDA 9.0, CUDA 9.2, CUDA 10 (with different cuDNN for specific version + different tensorflows according to the table, however it looks like there is something else missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for some reason this combo won't work.

Other with CUDA 10 worked.